# run failed error while using qsort in c++

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code for counting the frequency of names and then printing out the names in lexicographic order with their frequencies.The input here is supposed to be n number of names.So for sorting i wrote qsort function but i guess there is some error in it which i am not able to find bcoz using using other sorting method besides qsort works fine for this code.Please suggest what is the error as i have tried but found no help.below is the code snippet

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct stu
{
char name[100];
int no;
};
int cmpfunc(const void* p,const void *q){
struct stu *a = *((struct stu**)p);
struct stu *b = *((struct stu**)q);
int str=strcmp(a->name,b->name);
if(str>0) return 1;
if(str<0) return -1;
else return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n,k=0;
scanf("%d",&n);
struct stu* data[1000];
for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
    char nam[100];
    scanf("%s",nam);
    if(i==0)
    {
        struct stu* temp=(struct stu*)(malloc(sizeof(struct stu)));
        strcpy(temp->name,nam);
        temp->no=1;
        data[k++]=temp;
    }
    else
    {
         int j;
         for(j=0 ; j<k ; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(data[j]->name,nam)==0)
            {
                data[j]->no++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j==k)
        {
            struct stu* temp=(struct stu*)(malloc(sizeof(struct stu)));
            strcpy(temp->name,nam);
            temp->no=1;
            data[k++]=temp;
        }
    }
}
    qsort(data, k, sizeof(struct stu*),cmpfunc);
    for(int i=0 ; i<k ; i++)
{
    printf("%s %d\n",data[i]->name,data[i]->no);
}
return 0;
}
```

if i give input as

```
5
abcd
abcd
fgh
fgr
fgh
```

the output is run failed

Comment: give a example where your code stops working

Comment: How many valid elements is there in the array `data`, are there `n` elements (as you tell `qsort`) or `k` elements (which you use when printing)?

Comment: i should have passed k as argument in place of n.just edited.

Comment: I just realized you're using C++, not C. `<cstdlib>` does not exist in C.

Comment: using stdlib.h also didnt help

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @anoopknr the while running after giving the input the output is just a run failed error

Comment: What do you mean by "run failed error"?

Comment: @melpomene output is just an error which states   RUN FAILED

Comment: It seems to work as intended. I have the output `abcd 2
fgh 2
fgr 1` with your proposed input

Comment: If that change wasn't the problem then [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If it *was* the problem you should not change your code in the question, and instead tell us so we could write that as an answer.

Comment: `struct stu* temp=(struct stu*)(malloc(sizeof(struct stu))); /* where's your error checking before */ strcpy(temp->name,nam); // ?!`

Comment: Is there anyone besides @Norgannon who got desired output.That would help me to check if there is any compiler related error

Comment: `/* I think you mean */ if (scanf("%d",&n) != 1) { /* emit some error and exit, perhaps? */ }`

Comment: @autistic what would this error checking be helping in???scanf one??i m nt getting

Comment: @return0 In order to create an MCVE, you need to eliminate potential causes of your runtime failure.

Comment: Have you ever used `valgrind`? I'm sure that'll give you much more info...

Comment: @autistic thanku for suggesting i'll try using this also.

Comment: Are you programming in C++ or C? Your question is tagged C++ and you have `#include <cstdlib>`, but all your other code is C. There are much better ways to do what you want in C++.

Comment: If I were you I'd get myself a good modern book on C++.

Answer (score 4):

With the exception of `<cstdio>`, your code looks much more like C than C++. Perhaps you meant to use `<stdio.h>`, heed various warnings against [casting `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), check return values and use a C compiler, but this question is tagged C++. In C++ there are far more sensible idioms, for example:

- `std::string` instead of `char*` / `char[]`.
- `std::cin`/`std::cout` instead of `scanf`/`printf`.
- `std::vector` instead of `struct stu* data[1000]`.
- `size_t` instead of `int` for array indexes and looping over arrays.
- `new`/`delete`/`unique_ptr` instead of `malloc`/`free`.

---

```
using namespace std;

struct stu {
    string name;
    int no;

    stu() {

    }
};

int cmpfunc(const stu *p, const stu *q) {
    return p->name < q->name;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    size_t n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<stu*> data;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string nam;
        cin >> nam;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            auto* temp = new stu();
            temp->name = nam;
            temp->no = 1;
            data.push_back(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < data.size(); j++)
            {
                if(data[j]->name == nam)
                {
                    data[j]->no++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j == data.size())
            {
                auto* temp= new stu();
                temp->name = nam;
                temp->no = 1;
                data.push_back(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), cmpfunc);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << data[i]->name << data[i]->no << endl;
        delete data[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Note for OP: step 4 also applies in C...*

Comment: In the big list of C++ features, the most important one (`std::sort` instead of `qsort`) is missing.

Comment: I’d say that `vector<stu>` makes even more sense. Or at the very least `vector<unique_ptr<stu>>` but that’s a pessimization unless the vector is being inserted to/removed from far from the end.